# how compile files contain apache avro in c++

Tags: c++, c, apache, avro

I wrote two program "sender" and "receiver" in c++.I want to send an object from sender to
receiver.I want to use Avro apache.
I read the documentation on apache site.I copy one sample from it.
But i cannot compile it.I move all the .cpp and .hh files of Avro to my project and include
all of them,but i doesn't work.What can I do?

Comment: Can you please post the OS you are using, the make command and the output of the compiler? Thank you.